# How to restore a model with tensorflow without using sessions?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tensorflow

I have a DNNClassifier I created and saved using

```
classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(
  feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3, model_dir=model_directory)
```

Something is then saved in the directory model_directory, I get the files

```
checkpoint
events.out.tfevents.1480518258.DESKTOP-E18T9HJ
graph.pbtxt
model.ckpt-100-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-1-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-100.meta
model.ckpt-1.meta
```

I then try to load it, using

```
new_classifier = learn.TensorFlowEstimator.restore(model_directory)
```

(according to what I saw [there](http://terrytangyuan.github.io/2016/03/14/scikit-flow-intro/) )
but get

```
File "importAndClassify.py", line 17, in <module>
  new_classifier = learn.TensorFlowEstimator.restore(model_directory)
File "/home/Alois/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/base.py", line 441, in restore
raise ValueError("Restore folder doesn't contain model definition.")
ValueError: Restore folder doesn't contain model definition.
```

Do you have any idea what I should do ? I read [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4086) "Restoring is done via providing the same model_dir to the constructor." but this gave no result.

```
new_classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(model_directory)
```

I am pretty confused with all the API changes and the lack of clear documentation. Especially, I don't get why on some tutorials, a classifier is built using tensorflow variables and a session and everything is very complex and some other times, well it sounds easy to do, you just have to say you want this classifier based on this and this parameter... Is this for parametrizing further ? Is there a bridge between those two visions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same opinion ... seams like they need some good software architectural and good project manager... this way tf looks like a joke

To solve your problem : the model automatically loads from that directory in the "constructor" :

classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(
  feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3, model_dir=model_directory)

if model_directory has the files it will load them ... that is how to load the model lol ... it really is nothing more

My problem is to load this same model in tensorflow in JAVA ... I need a "model_saved.pb" or "model_saved.pbtxt" file but it is impossible to get it using learn.DNNClassifier(...)